# Delete namespace from xmlstarlet output

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces, xmlstarlet, xmllint

## Background

Looking to extract elements from the following XML content:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:inputText id="id"/>
    ...
</ui:composition>
```

## Extraction

All `h:inputText` elements can be selected using:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//h:inputText" filename.xml
```

## Problem

This produces the following namespace-infested output:

```
<h:inputText
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" id="id"/>
```

## Question

How can the namespaces be suppressed from the output?

## Ideas

Use regular expressions to post-process; however:

- sed doesn't have a non-greedy match;
- perl is too heavyweight (and would require a complex regex).

Pipe through xmllint or xmlstarlet for a second pass, but that requires a well-formed XML document.

Using xmllint poses its own set of namespace problems.

Produce a document comprised of only `ui:composition` and `h:inputText` elements:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:inputText id="id"/>
  <h:inputText id="id"/>
</ui:composition>
```

This is tricky because the `h:inputText` elements can occur at any depth of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XSLT. If you want to output `h:inputText` as-is, you won't be able to suppress the namespace declaration binding the prefix `h:` to the uri `http://java.sun.com/jsf/html`.

## XSLT 1.0

Create `input.xsl`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//h:inputText"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h:inputText">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## xmlstarlet command

```
xmlstarlet tr input.xsl filename.xml
```

## Output

```
<h:inputText xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" id="id"/>
```

You could output `inputText` in no namespace though...

## XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" exclude-result-prefixes="h">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//h:inputText"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h:inputText">
    <inputText>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    </inputText>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Output

Using same command line above:

```
<inputText id="id"/>
```

Note: You might need to add `<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>` after `</xsl:copy>` (or `</inputText>` in the second example) to explicitly add a newline. Otherwise xmlstartlet might output all the elements on a single line. (It did for me using xmlstarlet 1.6.1 and `indent="yes"` on `xsl:output` didn't help.)

## JSF Output

Since JSF is involved, consider:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                exclude-result-prefixes="h f c ui a4j">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <h:html>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//h:inputText"/>
        </h:html>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h:inputText">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <h:inputText>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        </h:inputText>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

An XSLT-stylesheet solution has been posted some time ago but through
experimentation with xmlstarlet version 1.6.1 I recently happened on
a command-line ditto which produces the desired output
`<inputText id="id"/>`,

```shell
xmlstarlet sel -N = -t -m '//h:inputText' -e '{local-name()}' -c '@*' -b -n file.xml
```

where `-N =`  appears to bind an empty prefix to the null namespace.

If you add `<f:inputText id="id"/><ui:inputText id="id"/>` to the
input file and change the `-m` clause in the command above to
`-m '//f:inputText | //h:inputText | //ui:inputText'` it produces
the desired output for each matched node. This would be a roundabout,
and verbose, way to do `exclude-result-prefixes="f h ui"` on the
command-line.

Unsurprisingly, the [user's guide](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04.html) does not mention this use of `-N`, and the source code's [`parseNSArr(…)`](https://sourceforge.net/p/xmlstar/code/ci/master/tree/src/xml.c) offers no clues.
Perhaps it's by design - how could they fail to notice? - perhaps not:
the `-N =`  syntax is somewhat suspicious-looking. But I'd definitely
stay away from the `sed -e 's/ xmlns.*=".*"//g'` approach listed in the
[user's guide](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html).

Answer (score 0):

> sed doesn't have a non-greedy match

Is this still too greedy?

```
sed -e 's/ xmlns[^=]*="[^"]*"//g'
```